# Difference between shell and term

Tags: shell, term

I would like to understand what is the difference between `M-x shell` and `M-x term`? Also under which circumstances should be used the first and under which the second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html) is the oldest of the two.  It uses Emacs's `comint-mode` to run a subshell (e.g. `bash`).  In this mode, you're using Emacs to edit a command line.  The subprocess doesn't see any input until you press Enter.  Emacs is acting like a dumb terminal.  It does support color codes, but not things like moving the cursor around, so you can't run curses-based applications.

[`term`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html) is a terminal emulator written in Emacs Lisp.  In this mode, the keys you press are sent directly to the subprocess; you're using whatever line editing capabilities the shell presents, not Emacs's.  It also allows you to run programs that use advanced terminal capabilities like cursor movement (e.g. you could run `nano` or `less` inside Emacs).

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104325/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-eshell-and-term-in-emacs) was originally [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104325/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-eshell-and-term-in-emacs)  by [cjm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2421/cjm) on the Unix Stack Exchange Site.

Comment: From what I read here `term` should be used instead of `shell` as it is more advanced, right?

Comment: It is primarily opinion based, usually the one you work more efficiently in. I personally prefer shell, because of color codes and I am used to it.